# Logger or System.out.print for debug statements in tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, logging

When writing debug statements out in unit tests, is it ok to give the test class a logger and use the same logging framework your production code uses, or should System.out.print be used?

Comment: It depends on your requirements of course. Most logging frameworks allow for having separate config files for testing and production code.

Comment: If you want to reuse as much as possible your code I advise to use a Logger, is a best way if you use Log Level (Info, Warn, Error, Debug, etc)

Comment: Question is not opinion-based. As @Xstian and others show, people can provide facts based on their experience and details to back up their answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it's always better to use logger than `System.out.print()`. And yes, it's a good idea to use the same framework for production and tests. In unit tests you can use another configuration file for logging, a special one only for tests. In such a configuration you can set different logging level etc.

Hava a look at [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) and [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/).